# How do I translate the following

Tags: traducción, español-neutral, jerga-internet

How do I translate the following message

```
Y aste le dune a my novio
```

Comment: Either text is not Spanish or there are mistakes in the transcription

Comment: What makes you think it's Spanish?  Where did you see it?  Was it from some very old document, like medieval?

Comment: Terrible title, the language isn't even spanish and there is no evidence of any effort whatsoever from OP

Comment: He añadido la etiqueta "jerga-internet". Es dificil saber si ese texto (tipo "HOYGAN" de algún chat o mensaje de texto o fuente/medio similar) pretendía ser español u otra cosa. A mi si me dijesen que es portugués me lo creéria. Quizá deberíamos decidir en meta si este tipo de preguntas son directamente off-topic o cómo deberíamos abordarlas.

Comment: @Diego Este tipo de mensajes son de texto (SMS) o enviados a través de un dispositivo móvil que usa la función de auto-correción para "auxiliar" con la ortografía (el lenguaje usado siendo inglés, no español). He batallado lo suficiente con Android para reconocer su "huella", la frase en cuestión parece ser "*hasta le doné a mi novio*" que puede interpretarse como una persona sintiéndose agraviada o insegura por el comportamiento de alguien que se quedó con su pareja, lo cuál se describe como "una donación" en su queja. En ese caso sería "*I even donated my boyfriend to him/her*".

Comment: @Diego Mi punto siendo que tal vez este tipo de peticiones se vuelvan más comunes, dado que el español usado no es entendible, por lo que es probable que los esfuerzos de la persona que realizó la pregunta no rendirán frutos. ¿Tal vez sería buena idea comenzar una conversación en Meta para llegar a un consenso acerca de qué hacer con peticiones de este tipo? ¿Qué se hace con peticiones de traducción normal? ¿Se le sugiere que el español presentado no es el correcto y se muestra cuáles son las frases más cercanas para que ellos intenten traducir basadas en ellas?

Answer (score 2):

*"And I even gave it to my boyfriend. "*

Given:

- **aste** - this is a typo for *hasta*
- **dune** — is a typo for *doné* — [donar](http://dle.rae.es/?w=donar&origen=REDLE) in [1st pret](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/Spanish/donar.html). (I donated)
- **my** — is a typo for *mi*

Comment: Dunir? Did you make a typo yourself or is it really a word? I've never ever heard it.

Comment: my bad, it was early. 'donar' .. I've edited it.